# Why is nondeterminism an undesirable property of a theory in physics?

Tags: determinism, stochastic-processes

According to the first paragraph of this [Wiki article on wave-function collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse#The_process):

> if collapse were a fundamental physical phenomenon, rather than just the epiphenomenon of some other process, it would mean nature was fundamentally stochastic, i.e. nondeterministic, an undesirable property for a theory.

My question is why? To my mind it sounds like physicists are trying to be choosey about the nature of the universe. This doesn't seem like a particularly impartial standpoint! The universe may well be fundamentally stochastic, it is not good science to disregard (or at least to be skeptical of) a theory only because it is not deterministic. Our job is supposed to be discover the nature of things, not to decide how we'd like them to be and ignore anything else!

Furthermore, why on Earth would anyone suggest that nondeterminism is undesirable? To accept determinism is to accept that you have no free will. Doesn't that rather take the joy out existence? I for one would much rather live in a stochastic universe, but in any case let's not get bogged down in philosophy. The question I have - to be clear - is why do physicists seem to shy away from nondeterministic theories? It surely is not our place to be picky about which theories we like and which we don't, we are supposed to be impartial.

Comment: As an aside, free will doesn't necessarily exist in a stochastic universe either. Random will is not the same as free will. Whether or not you can enjoy your existence may or may not be up to you, but it certainly does not depend on the answer to the free will question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is really a philosophy question.  However the answer is reasonably straightforward I think.

One of the useful characteristics of a theory of physics is that it allows you to predict the future: if you know the state of things at some time (or some suitable equivalent to that in SR or GR) then you can, in principle, solve the evolution equations, and say what the state is later on.

That's a thing people like to be able to do, and a thing that, before QM, it seemed that you always could do in principle.  But it's a thing that you can't always do if your theory is not deterministic.  So people tended to prefer theories which were deterministic, and the effective failure of determinism in QM famously made some very famous physicists unhappy.

But yes, the answer is indeed that it's our job to explore what the world *does* and not what we *want it do to*, and indeed that is why people accept QM despite all its inconveniences.

Comment: Also we grew accustomed to think that nature is deterministic. Until we started looking at the sub-atomic level determinism was never questioned because no counter example existed..

Comment: So your answer is essentially "we like determinism, but we are prepared to accept that it's not the case". I'm a happy with that, but then why do articles like the one I referenced feel the need to actively shun nondeterministic theories? To my mind that is only going to serve to discourage aspiring physicists from looking into those theories. (I respect that you can't actually answer for the author of the article. I was just curious as to what Physics SE had to say about it). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JeneralJames: I don't think the article 'shuns' nondeterministic theories: it says that nondeterminism is 'an undesirable property for a theory' which, other things being equal, it is for the reasons I've given, but it does *not* say that we should reject theories which make correct predictions on those grounds, and indeed people did not reject QM on those grounds.  (It also then goes on to talk about decoherence &c which purports to get away from this problem I think.)

Comment: I for one have not encountered many physicists who are truly unhappy with nondeterministic theories. Maybe those that are unhappy are just more vocal about their feelings than the rest of us.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: that's a good point I think: I've added it to my answer.